# How do I represent a Unicode character in a literal string ISO/ANSI C when the character set is ASCII?

Tags: c, unicode

In Perl, I can say

```
my $s = "r\x{e9}sum\x{e9}";
```

to assign `"résumé"` to `$s`.  I want to do something similar in C.  Specifically, I want to say

```
sometype_that_can_hold_utf8 c = get_utf8_char();
if (c < '\x{e9}') {
    /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For UTF8, you have to generate the encoding yourself using rules found, for example, [here](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=e9&mode=hex). For example, the German sharp s (ß, code point 0xdf), has the UTF8 encoding 0xc3,0x9f. Your e-acute (é, code point 0xe9) has a UTF8 encoding of 0xc3,0xa9.

And you can put arbitrary hex characters in your strings with:

```
char *cv = "r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9";
char *sharpS = "\xc3\x9f";
```

Comment: If the variable is wide enough to hold UTF-16, can you say \x00e9?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a C99 compiler you can use <wchar.h> (and <locale.h>) and enter the Unicode code points directly in the source.

`$ cat wc.c`

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
  const wchar_t *name = L"r\u00e9sum\u00e9";
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  wprintf(L"name is %ls\n", name);
  return 0;
}
```

`$ /usr/bin/gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall wc.c`

`$ ./a.out`

```
name is résumé
```

Comment: While the above code does work, it is paramount to mention that `wchar_t` is not necessarily able to represent multiple locales at once. It only has to be wide enough to support the current locale.

Comment: "wide enough to support the current locale" i.e. [MB_CUR_MAX](https://man.archlinux.org/man/MB_CUR_MAX.3) i.e. `size_t __ctype_get_mb_cur_max()`

Answer (score 1):

wchar_t is the type you are looking for: http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wchar.h.html

Comment: Just keep in mind that that's a *UNIX* spec (SUS), not part of ISO C. I only bring it up since there was no unix tag on the question.

Comment: I am more interested in how to render é in ASCII text in C, In Perl I can do it by saying `"\x{e9}"`.  The problem is that the source is in ASCII, but it needs to create UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @Chas: Why not use a UTF-8 as the source file encoding? Most compilers shouldn't have any problem with that as long as the multibyte sequences only occur inside string literals...

Comment: Because the source is going thorough a system that requires it to be 7-bit clean.  I am just happy I don't have to use trigraphs (e.g. `??=` for `#`).  Note, the source is going through that system, not being compiled there.  Yes, I know it is silly.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t` `setlocale()` seems *optional*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  const char *const name = "r\u00e9sum\u00e9";
  printf("name is %s\n",name);
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ /usr/bin/gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra bc.c
$ ./a.out
name is résumé
```