# C String Literal "too big for character"

Tags: c, string, literals

With MSVC 2010 i try to compile this in C or C++ mode (needs to be compilable in both) and 
it does not work. Why? I thought and found in the documentation that '\x' takes the next two characters as hex characters and not more (4 characters when using \X").

I also learned that there is no portable way to use character codes outside ASCII in C source code anyway, so how can i specify some german ISO-8859-1 characters?

```
int main() {
     char* x = "\xBCd";  // Why is this not char(188) + 'd'
}

// returns  test.c(2) : error C2022: '3021' : too big for character
// and a warning with GCC
```

Comment: `unsigned char` vs `char`? `char` is most likely signed, in which case values above 127 are "too big".

Comment: Thanks but no. I tried it with unsigned char too. Same error message.

Comment: @Lothar: I don't mean to be a nazi, but you mean ANSI C instead of ASCII C right? ;) Also, you're right that there is no real portable way of doing unicode. You'll need to specify the encoding yourself if you are using a charset > 8bit. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421811/how-do-i-represent-a-unicode-character-in-a-literal-string-iso-ansi-c-when-the-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately you've stumbled upon the fact that `\x` will read every last character that appears to be hex<sup>1,2</sup>, instead you'll need to break this up:

```
const char *x = "\xBC" "d"; /* const added to satisfy literal assignment probs */
```

Consider the output from this program:

```
/* wide.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    const char *x = "\x000000000000021";
    return printf("%s\n", x);
}
```

Compiled and executed:

```
C:\temp>cl /nologo wide.c
wide.c

C:\temp>wide
!
```

1. Tested on Microsoft's C++ compiler shipped with VS 2k12, 2k10, 2k8, and 2k5
2. Tested on [gcc 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/yXkbnM).

Comment: My Vim syntax highlighter seems to agree with this rule. Anyhow, `x` should probably be a `char const*`.

Comment: Another option is to switch to octal: `"\274d"` is interpreted as a two-char string, as is `"\2740"`.

Comment: @bitmask: I believe you meant `const char*`.  `char *const` would declare a const pointer, but that's not what needs to be const here

Comment: But using octal will i not just run into the same problem, only restricted to following 0-7 this time? Or is octal really defined to exactly three digits?

Comment: @Lothar: octal uses only 3 digits as far as I can tell. `\x` and `\X` merely differentiate the "width" of the resulting character.

Comment: @EdS.: No I meant `char const*`, not `char* const`.

Comment: @bitmask: Ok, I misread.  That's a very strange way to write `cont char*` though as it accomplishes the exact same thing, just in a less idiomatic manner.

Comment: @EdS.: As a matter of fact, it's not. I cannot go into detail in a comment, but there are lots of advantages (readability wise) to always put the cv-qualifiers right, not left of the qualified type. It's not uncommon.

Comment: @bitmask: Well, I realize that reading the declaration right to left is the intended way to read them, and I also realize that putting it in the beginning is a special case, but I think you'll have a really hard time arguing that putting the const qualifier after the type is more common than the opposite.  It is of course a matter of style, so meh, fair enough.